# A new user can login after registering until i manually change the password in admin console

Tags: python, django

I do not know what's happening with the user login, when a user registers, everything is saved in the database when I check the admin console, but when the user wants to log in it doesn't authenticate the password. But if I go to the admin console and manually change the user password even to the same password that the user registered with then, then the user login will in successfully. I tried this like 10 times, it won't authenticate the user until I manually change the password. I hope to get a response soon because I have gone over my codes severally. `Below is my views.py. Thank you.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from newapp import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


def userreg(request):
    form = forms.UserInfoForm()
    otherform = forms.UserProfileInfoForm()
    registered = False
    newname = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.UserInfoForm(data=request.POST)
        otherform = forms.UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and otherform.is_valid():
            newname = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')

            user = form.save()

            user.set_password(user.password)

            user.save()

            profile_form = otherform.save(commit=False)

            profile_form.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile_form.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

            profile_form.save()

            registered = True



    return render(request, 'newapp/register.html', context={'form': form, 'otherform':otherform, 'newname':newname, 'registered':registered})





def userlogin(request):

    invalidlogin = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        print(user)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Sorry Your Account is not active")
        else:
            invalidlogin = 'OOPS! Your Username or Password is incorrect'
            print(f"{username} tried to login with {password}")
            return render(request, 'newapp/login.html', context={'invalidlogin': invalidlogin})

    else:
        return render(request, 'naijadict/login.html')
    return render(request, 'newapp/login.html')


@login_required
def userlogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Comment: set_password = When the raw_password is None, the password will be set to an unusable password, as if set_unusable_password() were used.
You are passing a None password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have a password field on your form. To set an inputted password do the following changes,

```py
password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')

user.set_password(password)
```

Hope this works.